# Session save path : session expiration

Tags: session-variables, php

Since my ubuntu server was clearing sessions too early I decided to use another folder to store the sessions. So I use something like the following:

```
session_save_path(SESSION_PATH);
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
session_start();
```

I attach this in every php file that needs a session_start() [I hope this is the right implementation]

My `logout.php` file does seem to clear the stored sessions in this custom directory. However my question is what if the user doesn't logout and just closes the browser. Do these session files from the custom folder get deleted over time?

Comment: 1 is the default for `session.gc_probability`, so what are you expecting to change from the normal behavior?

Comment: @CBroe yes the default value is 1. Someone commented on the session_save_path php documentation that this value must be manually set for a debian server. I am not sure if I need this for a ubuntu server. I just used it to be on the safe side.

Comment: If you are referring to a specific comment, please provide a link to it directly. (The commentor's names work as anchor links in the PHP manual.)

Comment: @CBroe [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php#98106) here you go :)

Comment: Well that comment basically says once you do this, garbage collection will work as normal.

Comment: @CBroe but when are these deleted? In my server they have been there for days now!

Comment: The manual page about the session settings describes how the garbage collector gets invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it will be cleaned by php engine.

> Garbage collection may occur during session start (depending on session.gc_probability and session.gc_divisor).
>   [Ref: PHP Documents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime)

in the other hand it would be enough to set session.gc_maxlifetime option.